# How to convert multiple columns headers to a new column in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given the following dataframe schema df_base:

```
root
 |-- contact: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dept: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- finance: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sales: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hr: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
```

and convert it to this df_type :

```
root
 |-- contact: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dept: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- deptType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
```

So that df_base columns of dept (sales, hr, fanance ) become the value for a new column depType of df_type.

Comment: @steven explode doesn't work on structures only on arrays I think. Or am I looking at it wrong ?

Comment: well you can just try lol. It doesn't cost much. Is the struct containing always only 3 items or it may vary?

Comment: @Steven True, I just tried it doesn't work is says type mismatch. This is a simplified example in reality it can contain 15 different items but it doesn't vary.

Comment: so when for each row only one of `["finance", "sales", "hr"]` will be present right? the other values will be null? It would helpful to provide some sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this :

```py
from functools import reduce

from pyspark.sql import functions as F


dept_type_list = ["finance", "sales", "hr"]

df_type = reduce(
    lambda a, b: a.union(b)
    (
        df_base.select(
            "contact",
            F.lit(dept_type).alias("deptType"),
            F.col(f"dept.{dept_type}.id").alias("id"),
            F.col(f"dept.{dept_type}.description").alias("description"),
        )
        for dept_type in dept_type_list
    )
)
```

You need to use the `struct` function then to get your nested final structure.